# How do I check if a dataframe column contains any values of a dictionary and if true copy the dictionary values in a new column of the DF?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, contains

I am trying to accomplish three things. First, I want to check if any of the values in a `dictionary` are contained within any values of a `dataframe` column. Second, for each value in the `dataframe` column that contain a `dictionary` value, I want to enter that `dictionary` value in a new column alongside the column that is being checked. Third, I want to enter the associated key of the `dictionary` values in a new column. I think I am stuck at the `if condition` on determining if the contain function is true. Note this is just a sample and the true dictionary will  have hundreds of keys/values and the dictionary have about a million rows. Also, although rare, the `dataframe` column may contain multiple values from dictionary. If there is a better way to do all of this, I am open to it.

Dictionary - dict1:

```
{'Delay one': ['this delay happens', 'this delay may happen'],
 'Delay two': ['this delay happens a lot', 'this delay happens almost'],
 'Other': ['this delay occurs']}
```

Dataframe - df2:

```
col1            col2                             col3
0     1   1/1/2021 2:07         this delay happens often
1     2  1/5/2021 19:21    this delay happens a lot here
2     3   1/1/2021 2:51   this delay happens almost alot
3     4   1/1/2021 5:24  this delay happens almost never
4     5   1/1/2021 5:24                              nan
5     9  1/1/2021 10:55                             null
```

Desired Result:

```
col1    col2    col3    contain_value   associated_key
0   1   1/1/2021 2:07   this delay happens often.   this delay happens  Delay one
1   2   1/5/2021 19:21  this delay happens a lot here.  this delay happens a lot    Delay two
2   3   1/1/2021 2:51   this delay happens almost alot. this delay happens almost   Delay two
3   4   1/1/2021 5:24   this delay happens almost never.    this delay happens almost   Delay two
4   5   1/1/2021 5:24   NaN NaN NaN
5   9   1/1/2021 10:55  Null    NaN NaN
```

Code:

```
# create dictionary
dict1 = df.groupby('col2')['col3'].agg(list).to_dict()

# Series created from dataframe so that contain function can be used; not sure if entire dataframe # can be used with contained function and if that would be better
series = df2['col3']

# function - if value in series contains any dict1 values put dict1 value in new column

def contain(note):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        for v in range(len(value)):
            contain = series[(series.str.contains(value[v]))]
            if contain:
                return v
    
# apply function to get dictionary values that are contained in DF column
df2['contain_value'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: contain(x))

# Not sure how to incorporate in the contain function on how to get key
df2['associated_key'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: contain(x))
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HECTOR~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25036/3873876505.py in <module>
     25 
     26 # xact_notes_match_comments
---> 27 df2['contain_value'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: contain(x))
     28 
     29 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1096                 # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1097                 # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1098                 mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

C:\Users\HECTOR~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25036/3873876505.py in <lambda>(x)
     25 
     26 # xact_notes_match_comments
---> 27 df2['contain_value'] = df2['col3'].apply(lambda x: contain(x))
     28 
     29 

C:\Users\HECTOR~1.HER\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25036/3873876505.py in contain(note)
     20         for v in range(len(value)):
     21             contain = series[(series.str.contains(value[v]))]
---> 22             if contain:
     23                 return contain
     24 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: This is a job for .loc and str.contains.  It will also be faster than apply. Ex:    `for k,v in dict1.items(): df.loc[(df[col3].notnull()) & (df['col3'].str.contains('|'.join(v))), 'col4'] = k`. I am not sure if my code formatted! the docs explain this pretty well, let me know if i can help any more, just not sure if i can give the depth of answer SO usually requires. @hector.h2913

Comment: how feasible is reversing the mapping of the dict?

Comment: @IrisD thanks. first, I dont see the purpose of `col4` or the `=k` part. can you explain? I removed these and just did a return of `df2.loc[(df2['col3'].notnull()) & (df2['col3'].str.contains('|'.join(values)))]`. Not 100% there but im working through it. Second, I thought the contains function is suppose to return a substring from a larger string, like in your suggested code which I adjusted `this delay happens almost never` returns in col3 but `'this delay happens a lot'` and `'this delay happens almost'` dont return.

Comment: @IrisD Third how do I get a new column in my `df2` with the contained/matched value from `dict1`?

Comment: @enke If I understand you correctly, I dont think it is that feasible since there are multiple values for each key.

Comment: @hector.h2913 the formatting is weird so hard to see, but if you start with for `k, v in dict1.items():` that unpacks your keys and values so you can use them.  col4 is the new column with the assigned key, because if the key is contained in the column, you wanted to put the key in a new column. It is just an arbitrary name for a column, you can name it whatever you want.   I found this link really helpful when i was learning about .loc and assignment: https://towardsdatascience.com/conditional-selection-and-assignment-with-loc-in-pandas-2a5d17c7765b.

Comment: @hector.h2913 to be clear, col4 is the new column with the contained match value from dict1. Also if you start with unpacking your dictionary, you will have better results than with joining all values because the dict.values() is a list of lists, and unpacking allows you to access each list on its own vs a list of lists.

Comment: @IrisD thanks. I tried it but not successful with that. I just dont see how `df2.loc[(df2['col3'].notnull()) & (df2['col3'].str.contains('|'.join(v))),'col4']` is going to make a new column with `col4`. its seems the `loc` is more for selecting on columns that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your `contain` function should look like this::

```
def contain(note):
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        for v in range(len(value)):
            contain = series[(series.str.contains(value[v]))]
            if not contain.empty:
                return v
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).